# What is the domain name for the iCloud Activation Server?

Tags: icloud, activation-lock

I am just wondering if anyone had the current hosts of the iCloud Activation servers, as I am currently writing a script that utilizes them. Any help is much appreciated. I know that it used to be albert.apple.com, however I am away from home and don't have admin privileges to install a packet sniffer at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still albert.apple.com, I don't think it's changed.

- https://albert.apple.com/WebObjects/ALUnbrick.woa/wa/deviceActivation